# In QT::QDIR need to display treeview directory structure with filtering specific folders which should not be displayed

Tags: qt, treeview, pyqt

Using **QT::QDIR**, i m trying to display the set of directories in **Treeview** as it is displayed in Windows explorer when u select the folders icon.

I succeeded in displaying the folders in **treeview**. But there are certain folders need not to be displayed or needs to be hidden.

Using list of folders options in **QDIR** is there any way to specify the list of restriction folders.

Thanks
Mathan

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method : [QDir::setNameFilters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setNameFilters)
ther is an example in the Qt documentation

Comment: For this the input be list of directories or files to be displayed which is a huge set in my case. What i m expecting is using a list of few folders which should not be displayed as a input to same as setNameFilters and the remaining huge set of folders should be displayed.